# How to Convert calculated column in Spotfire to DAX in POwer BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to redo an analytic which is already there in Spotfire to Power BI. There is calculated column:

```
= DenseRank(If([Assessed]="Yes",[Date],Null),"desc",[Application Content Id])
```

Can anyone help me with converting this calculated column to Power BI?

Comment: The PowerBI Equivalent to DenseRank would be to use the RankX function, with DENSE as the final argument. The rest appears to be pretty inline with how powerbi would do things.

Comment: I tried using RANKX(Table',IF([Assessed ]="Yes",[Effective Date].[Date],BLANK(),[Application Content Id],DESC),Dense) but it is throwing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following formula:

```
Rank = RANKX(Table,IF(Table[Assessed]="Yes",Table[Effective Date],BLANK()),Table[Application Content ID],DESC,Dense)
```

Looks like you are closing the brace before declaring the rank as dense. Give the above calculation a try and let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: Is it the same case if we want to covert to DAX                                           
Calculated column= Rank([COlumn 1],[Column 2])(In spotfire)

Comment: Yes, you can use a calculated column as a sorting variable as well

Comment: Could you please give an example, I am new user of Power BI so not clear about it

Comment: Check out this video which illustrates how you can rank by two columns:https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/ae7ntp/rank_by_multiple_columns_in_rankx_measure/